# Carofredsel and jQuery UI tabs elements hidden

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

I have set up `caroufredsel` inside of a jQuery tabs, but all of the elements inside the tabs are invisible. It seems that the `caroufredsel` wrapper height and width are both set to `0`, and the overflow is set to `hidden`.

I can see that `caroufredsel` is creating the proper wrapper and including my content into it, but the content is invisible. Anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone else facing such an issue, I was able to resolve the issue by using the jQuery('#carousel').trigger('updateSizes'); on tab click

Comment: Same here. It seems the carousel is watching its container and, when it's hidden, sets all sizes to zeros.