# How can I updateSize for CarouFredsel when inside of an accordion?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, caroufredsel

I'm using jquery accordion to hide/show content.  When the content is expended in the accordion - the carousel is hidden (the carousel is shown as expected if the accordion is set to open by default).

My issue seems similar to this one in regards to tabs:

[Carofredsel and jQuery UI tabs elements hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546612/carofredsel-and-jquery-ui-tabs-elements-hidden)

I have tried to apply their suggestion within my accordion call, but this does not work (the carousel still does not show/resize when the accordion expands/opens):

```
$( ".dnd-accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        var expanded = $(this).data("expanded");
        if(expanded===0){
            expanded = true;
        }
        else{
            expanded = expanded-1;
        }
        $(this).accordion( "option", "active", expanded);
    },
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('.dnd-carousel').trigger('updateSizes');
    }, 

});
```

And I've tried this as well, same thing, doesn't work:

```
$(".dnd-accordion .accordion-heading").click(function () {
    $('.dnd-carousel').trigger('updateSizes');
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or if there is a more correct solution?

**EDIT:**

Here is the html -

```
<div class="dnd-accordion dnd-toggle" data-expanded="0">
    <!-- ... accordion toggle content ...  -->

    <div class="dnd-accordion-body">
        <div class="dnd_container">
            <!-- ... accordion body content ...  -->

            <div class="dnd-carousel" data-autoplay="1" data-items="1" data-effect="scroll" data-easing="linear" data-duration="500">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="<!-- /path/to/image/ -->" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="<!-- /path/to/image/ -->" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="<!-- /path/to/image/ -->" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="<!-- /path/to/image/ -->" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="<!-- /path/to/image/ -->" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="<!-- /path/to/image/ -->" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="<!-- /path/to/image/ -->" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="<!-- /path/to/image/ -->" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="<!-- /path/to/image/ -->" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- [END] .dnd-carousel -->

        </div><!-- [END] .dnd_container -->
    </div><!-- [END] .dnd-accordion-body -->

</div><!-- [END] .dnd-accordion -->
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML for this?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my post with the html.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work 100%, I had a similar problem, and this did the trick

```
$(".dnd-accordion").on('click', '.accordion-heading', function () {
    $('.dnd-carousel').find('ul').trigger('updateSizes');
});
```

Now the part that's worrying me is the `'.accordion-heading'`, if it doesn't work try with `'.ui-accordion-header'`.